# How to capture data attribute for each row in lwc without event.currentTarget

Tags: lightning-web-components, data-set

[image]

I am validating a form on submit, I capture the field value by iterating over all fields using fieldname, i want to additionally capture the id for each iteration that I am setting as a data attribute on html  like this -

I am thinking I cannot use something like -
assessmentResponseSubmitted.Id = e.currentTarget.dataset.recordid;

Comment: I also tried  -  assessmentResponseSubmitted.Id = e.target.dataset.recordid;

Comment: I suggest you add whole code that is easily reproducible. By producing code that is easily  reproducible the chances of getting it answered is high. Also instead of screenshot please have the code typed out.

Comment: `<template for:each={wrapperList} for:item="wrapper">  
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={wrapper.Id} object-api-name="va_Questions__c" key={wrapper.Id}> 
   <lightning-output-field field-name="va_Question__c"></lightning-output-field> 
   <lightning-input-field field-name="va_Response__c" name="va_Response__c" onchange={handleInput} data-recordid={wrapper.Id} class="fieldsToValidate"></lightning-input-field> 
<lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" label="Submit Assessment" onclick={handleSubmit}></lightning-button>

Comment: handleSubmit(e){
let fields = this.template.querySelectorAll(".fieldsToValidate");
let assessmentResponseSubmitted = {};
        for(let i = 0;i < fields.length; i++){
            if(fields[i].fieldName == "va_Response__c"){assessmentResponseSubmitted["va_Response__c"] = fields[i].value;
assessmentResponseSubmitted["Id"] = e.target.dataset.recordid;}}
this.assessmentResponsesSubmitted[e.target.dataset.recordid] = assessmentResponseSubmitted;
        processResponses({strJSONData: JSON.stringify(Object.values(this.assessmentResponsesSubmitted)),isFinalSubmission:true}));}`

Comment: the issue i am facing is not being able to grab data-recordid={wrapper.Id} on {handleSubmit} @MohithShrivastava